# Авторизация в домене

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

есть часть машин, которые работают на fedora 13 и ubuntu 11.10.

так, при вводе логина (например) IIvanov, в fedore заходит, а в ubuntu нет (в ubuntu нужно вводить только все доменные именна с маленькой (iivanov).

Как исправить ubuntu, чтобы под ней можно было входить и как IIvanov, и как iivanov?

Answer (score 2):

попробуй в самбе прописать default case = upper/lowerмогу ошибаться, но вроде так. Это отключит чувствительность к регистру для samb'ы